I have a fresh Ubuntu 24.04 desktop with DHCP and it adds another nameserver to its network config
I've just started using Ubuntu on my laptop. After setting up I couldn't connect to my server via SSH. After some digging I found out the DHCP client on my laptop and server (both running Ubuntu 24.04) sets my default gateway as a secondary DNS server, even though this is not configured on the DHCP server and no other device on my network does this.
I first found it out from the network settings. This is the case for Ethernet, Wi-Fi and VPN if DHCP is used.
Ubuntu 24.04 Desktop Wi-Fi settings:

Then I checked the resolv.conf settings, which of course showed 127.0.0.53. Then I checked systemd-resolvconf.
user@lenovo:~$ cat /etc/systemd/resolved.conf 
#  This file is part of systemd.
#
#  systemd is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it under the
#  terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as published by the Free
#  Software Foundation; either version 2.1 of the License, or (at your option)
#  any later version.
#
# Entries in this file show the compile time defaults. Local configuration
# should be created by either modifying this file (or a copy of it placed in
# /etc/ if the original file is shipped in /usr/), or by creating "drop-ins" in
# the /etc/systemd/resolved.conf.d/ directory. The latter is generally
# recommended. Defaults can be restored by simply deleting the main
# configuration file and all drop-ins located in /etc/.
#
# Use 'systemd-analyze cat-config systemd/resolved.conf' to display the full config.
#
# See resolved.conf(5) for details.

[Resolve]
# Some examples of DNS servers which may be used for DNS= and FallbackDNS=:
# Cloudflare: 1.1.1.1#cloudflare-dns.com 1.0.0.1#cloudflare-dns.com 2606:4700:4700::1111#cloudflare-dns.com 2606:4700:4700::1001#cloudflare-dns.com
# Google:     8.8.8.8#dns.google 8.8.4.4#dns.google 2001:4860:4860::8888#dns.google 2001:4860:4860::8844#dns.google
# Quad9:      9.9.9.9#dns.quad9.net 149.112.112.112#dns.quad9.net 2620:fe::fe#dns.quad9.net 2620:fe::9#dns.quad9.net
#DNS=
#FallbackDNS=
#Domains=
#DNSSEC=no
#DNSOverTLS=no
#MulticastDNS=no
#LLMNR=no
#Cache=no-negative
#CacheFromLocalhost=no
#DNSStubListener=yes
#DNSStubListenerExtra=
#ReadEtcHosts=yes
#ResolveUnicastSingleLabel=no
#StaleRetentionSec=0

and resolvctl directly:
user@lenovo:~$ resolvectl status
Global
         Protocols: -LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
  resolv.conf mode: stub

Link 2 (enp0s31f6)
    Current Scopes: none
         Protocols: -DefaultRoute -LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported

Link 3 (wlp0s20f3)
    Current Scopes: DNS
         Protocols: +DefaultRoute -LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
Current DNS Server: 192.168.0.1
       DNS Servers: 192.168.0.207 192.168.0.1
user@lenovo:~$ 

I can see that resolvctl is setting this nameserver, I just don't know why. Is this an expected behavior? Do I just have to accept this and use manual DNS settings for all local network?

Scratch that, I reviewed my devices, and all of them has the default gateway in the DNS now. This was not the case for weeks. My TPLink AX1800 router is the one to blame. I don't know if this is caused by a firmware update or I just realized this now, but it is definately the DHCP server.
